# CSS3 column-count property is not working

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I'm trying to split a list into multiple columns once one exceeds the parent's (`ul`) height and I'm trying to do so with the `column-count` property but it doesn't seem to be working as the list is still condensed on a single column.

The heights of the `li`s are dynamic. When they exceed the height of the `ul` they just get squished on the same column but I want them to move to a second column.

```css
ul {
    max-width: 1180px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 95%;
}
li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    float: left;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li>5</li>
 <li>6</li>
 <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split the `ul` into multiple columns once the content **exceeds the specified height**, you don't need `column-count`. You just need `flex-wrap: wrap`.

Try this snippet:

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 49; i++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
  document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(li);
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 300px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

**Update**

Per the comment below, you can align the columns to the left by doing the following:

- `align-content: flex-start` to align the columns to the start of the flex container (the far left side since the `flex-direction` is column)
- then you will want to remove the default `padding-left` from the `ul` and maybe put a little
- use a little `padding-right` on the `li` elements for spacing.

Try the snippet below:

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 49; i++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
  document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(li);
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 300px;
  align-content: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

/* for slight space between the columns */
li {
    padding-right: 1rem; 
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

**Note**:

For brevity, I consolidated `flex-direction: column;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` by using `flex-flow: column wrap;`

Comment: This works great. Thanks a lot! Only one problem: I'd like to have the columns float to the left instead of spread out evenly in the container. Is that possible?

Comment: @opportunityr Sure I'll post an update with that code. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

This is Happened for using Flex Box Property. Remove display flex and try then. Hope that it will be solve your problem

Comment: I changed it to `display: block` and it's still not working. Now it's overflowing the container.

Comment: Please remove float: left from li.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  max-width: 1180px;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 300px;
  width: 95%;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```